# Using subclass static property in base class

Tags: python

I have one base class and other classes inherit from this class (subclasses). There is one common method in base class that I want to use subclass static properties If subclass has the properties; otherwise default base class property should be used.

I have written following code to do such a thing:

```
class Base:
  prp1 = 1
  prp2 = 2

  def __init__():
    pass

  def method1(self):
    # print subclass prp1 and prp2 if exist (how to do this?)

class Subclass(Base):
  prp1 = 3
  prp2 = 4

a = Subclass()
a.method1() # should print subclass properties (3, 4)
```

How to get around this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `self.prp1` and `self.prp2` what you describe is normal attribute resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine - you can reference `prp1` and `prp2` using `self`, so:

```py
    def method1(self):
        print(self.prp1)
        print(self.prp2)
```

Will reference the properties from the instance of the class you're calling it on.

Furthermore, if you don't define `prp2` on the subclass, Python will fallback to `prp2` from `Base`, which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Isn't using "self" implying that it's an instance field whereas it's defined as a static field?

Comment: For starters, the name of the argument does not really matter, it's just naming convention.

Yes, it does "imply" that, but both attributes (fields) can be accessed this way.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the class from instance should do the thing:

```
print(self.__class__.prp1)
```